# How To Print Values Stored in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working to create a function where I take in 6 values (3 strings, 3 ints), store those values in arrays, then print out each of those values in pairs of 2

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    int time[SIZE] = {};        
    string name[SIZE] = {};     

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        cout << "Enter runner name: ";
        getline (cin, name[+1]);        
        cout << "Enter runner time: ";
        cin >> time[+1];
        cin.ignore();
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        cout << name << " finished in " << time << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
name1 finished in time1
name2 finished in time2
name3 finished in time3
```

Currently, my output looks like this:

```
0x22fdf0 finished in 0x22fe10
0x22fdf0 finished in 0x22fe10
0x22fdf0 finished in 0x22fe10
```

How can I get the inputs to be stored in the arrays then output those values to the user?

If this has been answered already, apologies.  I haven't been able to find an example where the arrays are populated with user input values and then returned to the display.

Comment: `getline (cin, name[+1]);` -- Kindly state what this is supposed to do?  What is the `name[+1]` about?  Looks like you're guessing what to write there instead of looking at a good C++ book as to how to read into an array using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually index the array using the `[]` subscript operator. Likewise, when printing, you should attempt to index an element in the array. Since when you attempt to print the array itself, the compiler will implicitly convert the array to a pointer, which, when printed, will print the memory address of the first element in that array, rather than the element itself.

So you could dereference the arrays to get the first value in each, but a better way is to index it by the `a` variable in your for loop, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 3;
    int time[SIZE] = {};
    string name[SIZE] = {};

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        cout << "Enter runner name: ";
        getline(cin, name[a]);
        cout << "Enter runner time: ";
        cin >> time[a];
        cin.ignore();
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        cout << name[a] << " finished in " << time[a] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to not index it, you could use your original approach, but then you would have to dereference the pointer using the `*` dereference operator:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    cout << *name << " finished in " << *time<< "\n";
}
```

However, now you would simply print the first element three times. So to remedy this, you need to employ some pointer arithmetic, and increase the value by a, to get the elements, 0, 1, and 2 past the first element respectively:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    cout << *(name + a) << " finished in " << *(time + a)<< "\n";
}
```

So some things to look up:
 * Dereferncing
 * Subscripting
 * Implicit array to pointer conversion

Comment: Suggestion: Kill the magic number 3. Replace `for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)` with `for (int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++)`